# Print specific sheets in excel doc to PDF with Python (xlwings)

Tags: python, pdf, printing, automation, xlwings

I am attempting to automate the very manual process of individually selecting a range of worksheets within an excel file to PDF. I was able to string together the following code, which successfully prints the document. However, I cannot figure out how to select specific worksheets within my workbook, so it currently prints the entire workbook to PDF (which comes out to a whopping 897 pages).

Any ideas on how to select certain pages and then print to PDF with a given file name?

```
import os
import xlwings as xw

book = xw.Book(r'linktomyfile.xlsm')
sheet = book.sheets[0]

current_work_dir = os.getcwd()
pdf_path = os.path.join(current_work_dir, "Report_Date.pdf")

print(f"Saving workbook as '{pdf_path}' ...")
book.api.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)

print(f"Opening PDF file with default application")
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the sheet reference to print to pdf, for example:

```
book = xw.Book(r'linktomyfile.xlsm')
sheet = book.sheets("Sheet1")

current_work_dir = os.getcwd()
pdf_path = os.path.join(current_work_dir, "Report_Date.pdf")

sheet.api.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)
```

You can also specify a range, e.g.

```
sheet.range("A1:G15").api.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)
```

Example of looping through specific sheets:

```
sheetlist = ["Sheet A", "Sheet B"]
for each in sheetlist:
    pdf_path = os.path.join(current_work_dir, f"{each}.pdf")
    sht = book.sheets(each)
    sht.api.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)
```

Here each pdf is named after the sheet name.

Comment: Where can I find a proper documentation for this API method?

Comment: @olenscki `api` simply gives access to Excel's VBA methods so its just as if you are writing VBA but with python syntax.  If there is no method in xlwings you simply look up how its done in VBA by either recording a macro or searching the Microsoft vba documentation, then you try and translate that to python syntax. The vba docs will tell you all the parameters that go with the method.

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of xlwings, there's a built in .to_pdf() function. Assuming you've got a book or sheet ready to print:

```
# to print a whole workbook
myXlwingsWorkBook.to_pdf(r"c:\myOutputPath")
# print a sheet
myXlwingsSheet.to_pdf(r"c:\myOutputPath")
```

Documentation: [Xlwings documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html) - then search for "PDF"

There're a few options. I wish I could just print/pdf the first page though...